# Morphia unwind aggregation returns different result than Mongo db query?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm trying to do a simple MongoDB aggregation here. Basically i have documents like this:

```
{
timestampInMs: 1444094140442,
records: [
{
value: "testvalue",
experiment: {
id: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
name: "integrationtest-kkkk",
created: "2015-10-03T22:47:38.479+0000",
updated: null
},
sensorId: "testsensor",
dataType: 1
},
{
value: "testvalue2",
experiment: {
id: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
name: "integrationtest-kkkk",
created: "2015-10-03T22:47:38.479+0000",
updated: null
},
sensorId: "testsensor2",
dataType: 1
},
{
value: "testvalue3",
experiment: {
id: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
name: "integrationtest-kkkk",
created: "2015-10-03T22:47:38.479+0000",
updated: null
},
sensorId: "testsensor3",
dataType: 1
},
{
value: "testvalue4",
experiment: {
id: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
name: "integrationtest-kkkk",
created: "2015-10-03T22:47:38.479+0000",
updated: null
},
sensorId: "testsensor4",
dataType: 1
}
],
created: "2015-10-06T01:15:40.501+0000",
updated: "2015-10-06T01:15:40.528+0000"
}
```

The java model looks like this

```
@Entity("sensordatadocs")
@Indexes ({
    @Index(fields = @Field("timestampInMs"), options = @IndexOptions(name = "timestamp_ms_index"))
})
public class DbSensorDataDocument {

    @Id
    // Should be milliseconds since Epoch
    private Long timestampInMs;

    @Embedded
    private List<DbSensorDataRecord> records;

    private Date created;

    private Date updated;
}

public class DbSensorDataRecord {

    private String value;

    @Reference
    private Experiment experiment;

    private String sensorId;

    private int dataType;
}
```

When I used the DB query

```
db.sensordatadocs.aggregate([{$unwind: "$records"}])
```

It gave me 4 documents, each document's "records" contains a single item which corresponds to item in the original array. However, when I used Morphia's API, like this:

```
Iterator<DbSensorDataDocument> iter = datastore.createAggregation(DbSensorDataDocument.class)
        .unwind("records").aggregate(DbSensorDataDocument.class);
```

It would return result like this:

```
{
timestampInMs: 1444094140442,
sensorId: "testsensor",
value: "testvalue",
experimentId: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
dataType: 1
},
{
timestampInMs: 1444094140442,
sensorId: "testsensor",
value: "testvalue",
experimentId: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
dataType: 1
},
{
timestampInMs: 1444094140442,
sensorId: "testsensor",
value: "testvalue",
experimentId: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
dataType: 1
},
{
timestampInMs: 1444094140442,
sensorId: "testsensor",
value: "testvalue",
experimentId: "56105b0af2763b25806d1365",
dataType: 1
}
```

This is how my iteration code looks like:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            DbSensorDataDocument doc = iter.next();
            final SensorDataRecord record = SensorDataUtils.flattenSensorDataDocument(doc);  
            result.add(record);
        }
```

Note that the number of items is correct, however, the values inside the "records" are incorrect, **in fact they are values of only the **first** item in the original array**. Why is this the case? Please help. Thanks!

Morphia version 1.0.1

Comment: It sounds stupid, but are you sure the iteration is done correctly?

Comment: I've updated the iteration code in the post. Should be correct ? O.O

Answer (score 0):

Reason of that behavior is Morphia cache issue. In your case Morphia treats all results of *DbSensorDataDocument* entities as same row (because of identical primary key *timestampInMs*), and returns **cached version**.

To solve this issue, you have to exclude field *timestampInMs* from results with aggregation projection:

```
Iterator<DbSensorDataDocument> iter = datastore.createAggregation(DbSensorDataDocument.class)
        .unwind("records").project(
 Projection.projection("timestampInMs").suppress(), 
 Projection.projection("XXXXXX").aggregate(DbSensorDataDocument.class);
```

Where XXXXX is a field that you want to include.